# Using twitter bootstrap in django

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms, django-templates

I am using twitter bootstrap tooltip. I have my base.html which include the file bootstrap.js In my template which extends the base.html, i have the script that is used to display the tooltip.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        console.log("In tooltip");
           $(".tip").tooltip();
        });
</script)
```

The problem is, the tooltip does not display in the current situation. If i import jquery library inside my template it does display the tooltip but the other features of bootstrap such as dropdown do not work then. 
I guess it is something really simple but I am particularly new to jquery.

**Updated**
The scripts are written in the following order in my files.

**base.html**

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   {% block content %}
   {% end block %}
</body>
```

In my template,

```
{% extends base.html %}
 {% block content %}

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bootstrap.js"></script>  (I have to call this and comment the one in the base.html for tooltip to work)

 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        console.log("In tooltip");
           $(".tip").tooltip();
        });
</script)
 {% end block %}
```

Comment: How are you loading your scripts? In what order?

Comment: @limelights do you mean in what order is it specified in my base.html ??

Comment: Canyou please check the update above. If it's ok ?

Comment: You're loading 2 versions of jQuery, you can remove the bottom one and you don't have to load your bootstrap.js again in your template if you already have it in your base.html

Comment: What a silly mistake..  :/ Thanks though..just curious to know, incase of having 2 versions of the same file..does it cancel some of the features in it..??

Comment: It can for sure. Also there's a stray closing paranthesis at the ending script tag.

Comment: @limelights can you also look at another question which has also to do with some django and javascript [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583126/jquery-ajax-post-to-update-django-sesions-in-views]