# Jquery Ajax post to update django sessions in views

Tags: jquery, django-forms, django-templates, django-sessions

I am sending the values from my form fields , so as to store them in sessions in django. I am doing the following, but it does not receive the data in POST in django.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var eventID = $('#id_eventID').val();
    var start = $('#id_start').val();
   $('a').click(function () {   
    console.log("Inside click");    
    $.post({
       url: "/update_session/",
       type: "POST",
       data: {eventID: eventID, start: start},
       success: function(response){},
       complete: function(){},
       error: function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
        alert("Error in ajax post");
       }
    });
    });
</script>

 <a href="Event/{{field.name}}"> Add signal</a>
```

I want this script to execute when i click on the link above, which in turn opens a new form. So, when i come back to the original page (after filling out the form), i want to be able to retrieve all the data which will be stored in sessions (in the way i did above).

In my **view.py** i have the following,

```
def update_session(request):
    print request.POST
    if request.is_ajax():
  try:
    request.session['eventID'] = request.POST['eventID']
    request.session['start'] = request.POST['start']
  except KeyError:
    return HttpResponse('Error')
    else:
  raise Http404
```

With this nothing get printed in my django termianl. It displays an empty Querydict{}.

Also, is my approach of achieving the required functionality correct ? or is there a better way to achieve this..I'm a novice with web development..
So, some source or hints would be great!

**Update:**
**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from EiEventService import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^$', views.event_view),
   url(r'^create/$', views.event_create),
   url(r'^eventSignals/$', views.eventSignal_create),
   url(r'^Intervals/$', views.interval_create),
   url(r'^eventBaseLine/$', views.EventBaseline_create),
   #url(r'^(?P<event_id>.*)/$', views.editEvent),
)
```

With changes in the view and adding the in urls.py as mentioned by limelights.
I am getting the following error. The entire traceback is,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 86, in run
  self.finish_response()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 127, in finish_response
  self.write(data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 210, in write
  self.send_headers()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 268, in send_headers
  self.send_preamble()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 192, in send_preamble
  'Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 324, in write
  self.flush()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
  self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 59495)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 582, in process_request_thread
  self.finish_request(request, client_address)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
  self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 150, in __init__
  super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 640, in __init__
  self.finish()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 693, in finish
  self.wfile.flush()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
  self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Comment: Well, there is nothing that i have specified in my urls.py wrt ajax request. I thought that it would use the url mentioned in the url inside post...I don't know what is to be written in url.py wrt ajax call...I read a few examples and there was nothing mentioned about urls.py

Comment: Well, you have to define the `/update_session/` url in the urls.py file in order for Django to pick it up. Could you please, post it?

Comment: Please have a look at the updated question with urls.py for my app. Also, is the way of achieving the desired result correct ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `/update_session/` url to your urls.py - this is the first and foremost problem you're having. This is also the reason for your script not reaching the server.

```
url(r'^/update_session/$', views.update_session)
```

Would be the url pattern for this.

Also, You're having a few other issues that will arise later on in your development so I would definately recommend you reading through the [tutorial here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04/)

Comment: I did add that and also changes the view a bit. But i get an error for which the traceback is printed. I also read the link which you mentioned, i know there are a lot of nitty-gritty that i need to resolve in my code. Is there anything there that you find buggy in my code that you say i'll have issues later in my development.

Comment: is it ok...that we just save the sessions in django via the ajax call and return nothing...session have to be used when rendering the parent form..I am assuming the sessions are stored in the server until it is has been deleted or a timeout has been set..Correct me if i'm wrong